# Facebook Share button parameters don't work properly?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I use this API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/
At the bottom of the page they have mentioned a way to create our own button.

So my code is like this:

```
<body>
    <?php    
    function encodeURIComponent($str) {
      $revert = array('%21' => '!', '%2A' => '*', '%27' => "'", '%28' => '(', '%29' => ')');
      return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
    }
    ?>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com'); ?>&t=<?php echo encodeURIComponent('It is the google website'); ?>">Share this2</a>

  </body>
```

But it is not working properly! And it **always displays the page title as the title in the share dialog!**

Answer (score 0):

See [*How does Facebook Sharer select Images?* answer from **OffBySome**](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images/7623986#7623986) can explain better then I.

---

An excerpt from some of the better answers:

In the head section of your HTML you need meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

You may need to force Facebook servers to clear the cache with the [Facebook Url Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: I tried this also and I put these 3 tags in the `head` tag of the page I am going to share but doesn't help!

Comment: You may need to force Facebook servers to clear the cache with the [Facebook Url Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).